# String a Array?

Tags: angular, jpa

Tengo un problema al convertir un String a un array. Lo que sucede es que manejo un array de la siguiente manera en angular.

Que como verán es este:

```
  ["TestName","Acceptance Criteria Start","Acceptance Criteria End","2","2","Difference","Pass/Fail"]
```

Pero cuando quiero hacer un update mis datos se almacenan sin las comillas por que el tipo de dato es string y es de jpa no se si deba de cambiarlo a un tipo array pero como tiene comunicación con otras tablas esto podría afectar a las demas quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de poder almacenar el string de la misma manera que el array?

La salida que obtengo al almacenar este array es esta:

```
['TestName,Acceptance Criteria Start,Acceptance Criteria End,2,2,Difference,Pass/Fail']
```

Answer (score -1):

Podrías hacerle un split a tu salida y guardarlo en un nuevo array de Strings:

```
String salida = "TestName,Acceptance Criteria Start,Acceptance Criteria End,2,2,Difference,Pass/Fail";
String[] salidaToArrayString = salida.split(",");
```

Comment: Ya intente generarlo con el Split De esa Manera pero me sigue guardando igual :S

Comment: al añadir el .split la salida es la misma y genera org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.String!

Comment: Y si a tu array que viene de angular le haces un join?:  String.join(",", arrayStringDeAngular);

Comment: lo mando como   private headerSend = new Array();

this.testSave = {
        'header': this.headerSend.toString(),
viene de esta manera no esta completo el string si lo pongo completo no creo que quepa